# How to create query in Laravel to db?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I wish to create query in Laravel from this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM kreditanfragen WHERE
send_bank='0'
AND (((beruf=6 || beruf=14 || beruf=29 || beruf=30 || beruf=31) AND netto>601) OR ((beruf1=6 || beruf1=14 || beruf1=29 || beruf1=30 || beruf1=31) AND netto1>601))
AND status_intern!=31
AND land='DE'
```

Comment: So, did you tried to do it? What code do you have at this moment? You should take a look at the [laravel queries docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could simplify your query as

```
SELECT * 
FROM kreditanfragen 
WHERE send_bank='0'
AND (
    beruf in(6,14,29,30,31) AND netto>601)
    OR
    beruf1 in(6,14,29,30,31) AND netto1>601)
)
AND status_intern != 31
AND land='DE'
```

And in query builder you could use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) to handle `or` case

```
DB::table('kreditanfragen')
            ->where('send_bank', '=', 0)
            ->where('status_intern', '<>', 3)
            ->where('land', '=', 'DE')
            ->whereIn('beruf', [6,14,29,30,31])
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->whereIn('beruf', [6,14,29,30,31])
                          ->where('netto', '>', 601);
                })->orWhere(function ($query) {
                    $query->whereIn('beruf1', [6,14,29,30,31])
                          ->where('netto1', '>', 601);
                });
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: @user9660776 it was a missing semi colon , i have updated answer you can check now

Answer (score 0):

Your query 100 % equivalent but it is no good.

```
DB::table('kreditanfragen')
    ->where('send_bank', 0)
    ->where(
        function ($query) use ($berufs) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($berufs) {
                $query
                    ->whereIn('beruf', $berufs)
                    ->orWhere('netto', '>', 601);
            })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($berufs) {
                $query
                    ->whereIn('beruf', $berufs)
                    ->orWhere('netto1', '>', 601);
            });
        }
    )->where('status_intern', '!=', 31)
    ->where('land', 'DE')
    ->get();
```

result is

```
"select * from `kreditanfragen` where `send_bank` = ? and ((`beruf` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) or `netto` > ?) or (`beruf` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) or `netto1` > ?)) and `status_intern` != ? and `land` = ?"
```

Correct way do same query

```
DB::table('kreditanfragen')
    ->where('send_bank', 0)
    ->where(
        function ($query) use ($berufs) {
            $query
                ->whereIn('beruf', $berufs)
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query
                        ->where('netto', '>', 601)
                        ->orWhere('netto1', '>', 601);
             });
    })->where('status_intern', '!=', 31)
    ->where('land', 'DE')
    ->get();
```

result is

```
"select * from `kreditanfragen` where `send_bank` = ? and (`beruf` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and (`netto` > ? or `netto1` > ?)) and `status_intern` != ? and `land` = ?"
```

Comment: in `orWhere` part you need `beruf1` and `netto1`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid see finally corrected answer (second part)

Comment: Thanks But please explaine why you type orWhere('land','de'), when In original just 'and'

Comment: it is mistake i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Each time i find myself faced with complex queries, i always use the DB::select() method as follows:

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM kreditanfragen WHERE
send_bank='0'
AND (((beruf=6 || beruf=14 || beruf=29 || beruf=30 || beruf=31) AND netto>601) 
OR ((beruf1=6 || beruf1=14 || beruf1=29 || beruf1=30 || beruf1=31) AND netto1>601))
AND status_intern!=31
AND land='DE'");
```